# how to NVDA screen reader read the tool-tip?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, css

I had also tried this but it not work

```css
<style>
/* Tooltip container */
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black; /* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
}

/* Tooltip text */
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
 
  /* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>

here i have attache the code of simple tooltip , i want the tool-tip read by the  screen reader i had also tried tabindex for focus but it not working
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use aria-describedby attribute

```
<a href="#" aria-describedby="myinfo">Texto de el Link</a>
<div role="tooltip" id="myinfo">Contenido de el tooltip]</div>
```